# Adding local Artifactory gem repo to gem sources fails

Tags: rubygems, artifactory

So I have a private gem repo setup on an Artifactory server (hosted on premise). The version of Artifactory I am using is 5.4.1 rev 50054 and I have configured it to use the default database and filestore.

The first time I create a brand new, clean rubygem local repo and add it to my local gem sources, I get an error like so -

> gem source -a http://server:8082/artifactory/api/gems/rubygems-local/
>   Error fetching http://server:8082/artifactory/api/gems/rubygems-local/:
>           too many connection resets (http://server:8082/artifactory/api/gems/rubygems-local/specs.4.8.gz)

However, as soon as Artifactory creates the below files in the repo (it usually takes about 30 seconds), adding it to gem sources is successful.

[image]

> gem source -a http://server:8082/artifactory/api/gems/rubygems-local/
>   http://server:8082/artifactory/api/gems/rubygems-local/ added to sources

Subsequently, if I remove the server and try to add it again, it throws an error like so -

> gem source -r http://server:8082/artifactory/api/gems/rubygems-local/
>   http://server:8082/artifactory/api/gems/rubygems-local/ removed from sources
>
> gem source -a http://server:8082/artifactory/api/gems/rubygems-local/
>   Error fetching http://server:8082/artifactory/api/gems/rubygems-local/:
>           server did not return a valid file (http://server:8082/artifactory/api/gems/rubygems-local/specs.4.8.gz)

If I wipe the repo as below (and wait for the index to be regenerated) or if I delete the cache directory on my local machine %USERPROFILE%.gem\specs\server%8082 and try again, it's successful.

[image]

> gem source -a http://server:8082/artifactory/api/gems/rubygems-local/
>   http://server:8082/artifactory/api/gems/rubygems-local/ added to sources

How do I diagnose and resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have any proxy server in front of your Artifactory instance that might intercept the request from the gem client to Artifactory?
In addition, what do you see in the request.log and artifactory.log?

Comment: @Ariel Sorry about the delayed reply and yes as it turns out it was the proxy server in between client and Artifactory. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @thegreendroid could you elaborate what was wrong with the proxy server? Also encountering this issue.

Comment: @spuder Unfortunately my memory fails me, I'll see if I can dig up anything.

Comment: My issue ended up being slightly different, root cause was a bad ssl cert. Explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56740466/no-such-name-when-attempting-to-add-ruby-gem-source

Comment: Hi. I saw the same issue. I cleaned up the remote repo's cache but still got the same error. How did you fix the error?