# `no such name` when attempting to add ruby gem source

Tags: rubygems, artifactory

I have an artifactory server that is acting as a gem repository.

When I try and change the gem sources, I get error `no such name`

```
gem source -a https://artifactory.example.com/api/gems/gems
Error fetching https://artifactory.example.com/api/gems/gems:
    no such name (https://artifactory.example.com/api/gems/specs.4.8.gz)
```

If I try and bypass the artifactory virtual repository, and point straight at the local repository I get error

```
gem source -a https://artifactory.example.com/api/gems/gems-local/
Error fetching https://artifactory.example.com/api/gems/gems-local/:
    bad response Not Found 404 (https://artifactory.example.com/api/gems/gems-local/specs.4.8.gz)
```

According to the artifactory documentation, the trailing slash does matter. I've tried the above examples with and without trailing slashes. All with the same result.

```
/api/gems/gems
/api/gems/gems/
/api/gems/gems-local
/api/gems/gems-local/
```

How can I further troubleshoot this? What is the proper way to add a gem source?

Answer (score 3):

To get more information for debugging, pass the `--verbose` option to the command line.

```
gem source -a https://foo.example.com --verbose
```

The error `no such name` is not a descriptive answer for the true problem. I had a misconfigured nginx reverse proxy infront of the artifactory server that was using the wrong internal SSL certificate. As soon as I fixed the certificate in nginx, I was able to connect to the gem repository properly.

Answer (score -1):

I just had this issue because I was on a VPN connection - it worked again after disconnecting from the VPN.